# iphone - set label font

Tags: iphone, uibutton, label

How can I set the font of button label to Century Gothic Bold of size 46.
I'm using following code:

```
        [self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Century Gothic-Bold" size:46]];
```

Is my code correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think iOS doesnt support your font. But there is a font called AppleGothic.

see this link

http://www.prepressure.com/fonts/basics/ios-4-fonts

Comment: Thanks for the update. If I've to select a font with name "Helvetica Neue Condensed Black" how show I code?

Answer (score 4):

```
 UIButton *NameBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    NameBtn=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    [NameBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [NameBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *textb=[[self.searchList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    CGSize constraintb = CGSizeMake(310 ,10);
    CGSize sizeb = [textb sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:constraintb lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [NameBtn setTitle:textb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NameBtn.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size: 12.0];
    NameBtn.frame = CGRectMake(85, 12, MAX(sizeb.width ,3.0f),12);
    [NameBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    NameBtn.tag=indexPath.row;

    [self.view addSubview:NameBtn];
```

Answer (score 1):

I used yesterday this:

```
onlineButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:onlineButton.titleLabel.font.pointSize+3];
```

So try this:

```
yourButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
```

Comment: Your way and my way of implementing is correct. But i want to know whether using the font name as mentioned in my code is correct or not......